# Export SAPUI5 Network Graph as PDF

Tags: sapui5

I'm trying to export the Ui control `sap.ui.commons.networkgraph.Graph` as PDF.
I follow this guide to rendering an org.chart

https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/sdk/#/sample/sap.suite.ui.commons.sample.NetworkGraphOrgChart/preview

I've tried `jspdf` to render but what I've got looks like this
[image]

I've also tried `html2pdf` as this link: https://github.com/eKoopmans/html2pdf.js to render but what I've got looks like this

[image]

AFAIK, these tools use svg string to render PDF. But the svg string I tried to retrieved from network graph is not enough. It miss the svg lines.
In the other hand, `sapui5`'s Vizframe do very well exporting to PDF, thanks to the provided `ExportToSVGString` method.

Any suggestions please ?
In the worst case, I would have to write a function to render these graphic to svg (like the method `exportToSVGString`).

Comment: What have you tried ? Give us more information ?

Comment: Hi, thank you for your concern sir. I've updated more info on this case